# C++ BST implementation overflows?

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I'm currently testing a BST implementation. However, when inserting increasing values, it fails.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned int uint;

struct node {
    uint data;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};

class ABB {
    private:
    node* root;
    node* insert(uint x, node* t);
    int find(node* t, uint x);

    public:
    ABB();
    void insert(uint x);
    int search(uint x);
};

node* ABB::insert(uint x, node* t) {
    if (t == NULL) {
        t = new node;
        t->data = x;
        t->left = t->right = NULL;
    }
    else if (x < t->data)
        t->left = insert(x, t->left);
    else if (x > t->data)
        t->right = insert(x, t->right);

    return t;
}

int ABB::find(node* t, uint x) {
    if (t == NULL)
        return 0;
    else if (x < t->data)
        return find(t->left, x);
    else if (x > t->data)
        return find(t->right, x);
    else
        return 1;
}

ABB::ABB() {
    root = NULL;
}

void ABB::insert(uint x) {
    root = insert(x, root);
}

int ABB::search(uint x) {
    return find(root, x);
}

int main() {
    ABB t;

    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
        t.insert(i);
    }

    cout << "done" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It never gets to print the "done". If I change the main function with the following:

```
int main() {
    ABB t;
    uint q = 40000;

    for (int i = 0; i < 40000; i++) {
        t.insert(q + i);
        t.insert(q - i);
    }

    cout << "done" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It end successfully, despite inserting more values. The 50000 is arbitrary, it stopped working around 44000. What could be wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works, it's just slow ([quadratic](https://accidentallyquadratic.tumblr.com/)) because your tree is unbalanced. You're essentially creating a singly-linked list in the first code, and on each iteration you have to traverse the whole tree.

Comment: it worked? then it's a memory problem I guess, I've got 16 GB RAM and I can't insert that number of increasing values

Comment: It worked for me. Another suggestion is literally stack overflow. Stack size may be altered, the exact way depends on your OS and compiler.

Comment: 44,000 recursive calls will use up a lot of stack space.

Comment: I still don't get it, when inserting ~250000 non-increasing random numbers, it works well, but increasing numbers don't. So no way to fix it (or change it)?

Comment: Yes, rewrite ‘insert’ to not use recursion - it’s not hard: enclose body in a while(true) loop, then change less/greater logic to set root to left/right instead of returning.